# Android set viewImage to ListView

Tags: android, listview

I need to set ImageView in my ListView. I download images to my list from net.
To do this i tried to extend BaseAdapter and override methods.
I am using [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper).
So i find a trouble. Sometimes i should show an image, sometimes not.
But my list cell always show an image.

```
class MySimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    ArrayList<WallMessage> posts;
    HashMap<Long, User> distinctUsers;
    Activity activity;
    WallMessage post;
    User user;
    LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public MySimpleAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<WallMessage> posts, HashMap<Long, User> distinctUsers) {
        this.activity = a;
        this.distinctUsers = distinctUsers;
        this.posts = posts;
        for(int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "attachSize = " + posts.get(i).attachments.size());
        }
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return posts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wall_item, null);

        TextView authorTv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.author);
        TextView postTv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.post); 
        TextView dateTv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.date); 
        TextView likesTv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.likes); 
        ImageView imagePhoto =(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto);
        ImageView imagePost = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imagePost);

        post = posts.get(position);
        user = distinctUsers.get(post.from_id);
        authorTv.setText(user.first_name + " " + user.last_name);
        postTv.setText(post.text);
        dateTv.setText(parseDate(post.date));
        likesTv.setText(Long.toString(post.like_count));
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imagePhoto, user.photo);

        if(post.attachments != null && post.attachments.size() != 0) {
            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imagePost, post.attachments.get(0).photo.src);
        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

I know that i have elements where post.attachments.size() == 0.
But my list all the same show images loaded from other cells.

Comment: Android adapters will reuse views, have you checked that you're clearing imagePhoto & imagePost (by calling ImageView.setImageBitmap(null) or something similar) in cases when there aren't any images?

Comment: Thank you, imagePost.setImageBitmap(null) worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using covertView you can get previously stored values in reused views.
Try :

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imagePhoto, user.photo);

    if (post.attachments != null && post.attachments.size() != 0) {
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imagePost, post.attachments.get(0).photo.src);
    } else {
        imagePost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // above can be any default url using UrlImageViewHelper 
        // or just some local resource like 
        // imagePost.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_default_drawable_resource);
    }
```

Comment: I replaced in your code.
imagePost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); --->
imagePost.setImageBitmap(null);
And now it is working correctly.